# Console Appears where Desktop Should

Tags: display, kde, chromebook

I've recently installed the Crouton package for my chromebook and have installed kde.  When I try to start it up I can get to the desktop just fine but if I switch back to my Chrome OS desktop and then back to the KDE Linux desktop it shows a console.

Forgive my extreme lack of knowledge surrounding this; ironically I tried to install linux to learn more about this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of memory and processing power of the chromebooks, it is probably closing kde to save you memory. You can start it again using the command `sudo startkde`.

I'm not  100% sure how chromebooks handles crouton and I know that this might not be the ideal answer but I hope that this will at least help you get back to your desktop without having to restart it.